# What is the difference between an 230V/120V AC automatic voltage regulator and a step up / step down voltage transformer / converter?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, mains, converter

There seem to be 2 kinds of devices to convert home mains AC power between 230V and 120V: some are named "automatic voltage regulator", and there are some labeled as voltage transformer or converter. Sometimes the same company makes both kinds, more or less at the same price and weight. Both seem to provide the same thing: both 230V and 120V outlets, regardless into which voltage they are plugged in (they have a switch to select which voltage you are plugging it in, or its automatic).

What are the technical differences between these, and which one should be used in which situation?

Comment: A link to both of them where you have seen the aforementioned terminology would be a good thing.

Comment: At a guess, I would say the transformer is a literal transformer, with a switch that can change its primary from two series windings to two parallel windings. These are very common and easy to find. The other one is likely a solid-state AC-DC converter with regulation.

Comment: Here are two by the same company, the same price, similar weight (but the transformer is 4.55 lb heavier): Automatic Voltage Regulator, 24.70 lbs: https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07D7JPJDP/ and step up&down transformer, 29.25 lbs: https://smile.amazon.com/LiteFuze-LT-5000-Voltage-Converter-Transformer/dp/B008GQTXS0/

Answer (score 1):

An automatic voltage regulator / constant voltage transformer / ferro-resonant transformer would be a special transformer that uses nonlinear magnetic properties and a resonant circuit to provide a stable output voltage over a wide range of input voltage. It could be either a 1:1 or a step-up / step-down transformer.

A step-up / step-down transformer would be a standard transformer performing only that function.

Answer (score 0):

The company SOLA used to manufacture regulation_transformers.

I'd see them off to the side of the lab, humming away, dissipating heat, and providing isolation against power_company noise and spikes and voltage fluctuations.

And probably against lighting strikes outside the building.

These transformers were on their own concrete mounting block, sitting a foot above the floor, and of size being a 4 foot cube. Inside the lab, so in air conditioning and likely to last forever.